# ASP.NET MVC ANGULAR Template URL routing issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a  question on how to configure the inbuilt login functionality URL in ASP.net MVC Angular template. The web api url for login is "Account/Login" .
 I add an href in layout.cshtml file as shown below

```
 <data-ng-class="{active : activeViewPath==='/contact'}">
<br>
< href='#/contact'>Contact</a></li>
<br>
 < data-ng-class="{active : activeViewPath==='/Login'}">
<br>
< href='~/Account/Login'>Login</a></li>

Now when I click any link(demo) , the functional URL is :
://ayz.com/#/demo

When I click Login (works fine):
://ayz.com/Account/Login#/home

When I click demo again (Account/Login gets appended):
://ayz.com/Account/Login#/demo

How to correct this ?

 $routeProvider
            .when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/main', controller: 'MainController' })
            .when('/contact', { templateUrl: '/home/contact', controller: 'ContactController' })
            .when('/about', { templateUrl: '/home/about', controller: 'AboutController' })
            .when('/demo', { templateUrl: '/home/demo', controller: 'DemoController' })
            .when('/product', { templateUrl: '/home/product', controller: 'ProductController' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ng-view /ng-route just changes the view that is a part of the angular only.!! 
As you were already in:  **//ayz.com/Account/Login**

```
//ayz.com/Account/Login#/home
```

When you click on demo, the view is just getting updated:

```
//ayz.com/Account/Login#/demo
```

Make sure, you use angular route for Account/Logon too.

Try getting the usage of hashbang too.!! Angular js uses that and just updates the part after that for ng-view.!!

Firstly when you were in demo: ayz.com/#/demo with no MVC routing.

And later on when you clicked on Accountlogin the url changed to ayz.com/Account/Logon/#home

and now when you clicked on demo, the last hasbang part of url "#/home" will just be changed to "#/demo" as you are now in Account/Login. And note that Angular routing works only for one ng-View in a single page.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear . I need //ayz.com/#/demo when I click Demo and //ayz.com/Account/Login#/home when I click login . Where would I need to update it ?

Comment: That was fine. Just add Account/Logon to your routing too and access through that.

Comment: Still no luck :

 $routeProvider            
            .when('/demo', { templateUrl: '/home/demo', controller: 'DemoController' })<br/>
            .when('/product', { templateUrl: '/home/product', controller: 'ProductController' })<br/>
             .when('/Account/Login', { redirectTo: '/Account/Login' })<br/>
                                  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });